# Unicode issues with acts_as_taggable_on_steroids

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unicode, utf-8, tags, acts-as-taggable-on-ster

I'm implementing a blog with tags with some French characters. My question has to do with how to deal with spaces and unicode (utf-8) characters in the url.

let's say I have a tag called: ohlàlà! and I have the following code in my tag cloud:

```
<%= link_to h(tag.name.capitalize), { :controller => :blog, :action => :tag, :id => h(tag.name) }, :class => css_class %>
```

How do I deal with this issue?

Comment: Edited my answer. It now references *Unicode and permalinks*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [ToASCII and ToUnicode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalized_domain_name#ToASCII_and_ToUnicode) in [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalized_domain_name). I hope the article has enough pointers to resolve your question.

*Edit:* Though it talks *Python*, [Unicode and permalinks](http://www.gooli.org/blog/unicode-and-permalinks/) can give an idea about how to encode a solution to your question. To summarize:

> Basically, the Unicode URL is encoded in UTF8 and each byte of the UTF8-encoded string is encoded using percent encoding. The browser apparently recognized this specific encoding scheme (which isn’t documented anywhere I could fine) and displays nice internationalized URLs for the user.

Sorry, I've no idea if *Rails* has a ready-made function to encode URLs this way.

Comment: thank you gimel. Very informative but I still would like to get specific help on how to apply this in Rails.